# QTextLabels not respecting their maximum size

Tags: qt

Despite setting the maximum width of a QTextLabel, when I lay it out horizontally in the MainWindow It exceeds its given maximum size.

[image: Aligned well]

[image: Exceeds maximum width]

Comment: refer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/15219564/1789729

Comment: Edit: Doesn't appear like it does in the screenshot when I compile it, appears normally.