# Sizing an embedded widget in QT

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, autoscaling

So I'm working on a QT5 based GUI and I have a main window that fills in an empty area depending on user input. The gui looks roughly like this

```
---------------------  
|Qlabel 1 |Qlabel 2 |  
|-------------------|  
|                |B1|  
|      MAIN      |B2|  
|                |B3|  
|-------------------|
```

B1,B2, and B3 are buttons which create popups that ask for user input. Main is the issue. In QT Creator I've set main to be a widget. I've also created a widget which has a layout (again in QT creator) which I'll call filler. On input an instance of filler, I add filler to a layout which I then set on main. The issue I'm having is that sizing seems to be totally dependent on the QT creator sizing of the layout inside of filler.
What I want is for filler to scale to the size of the encapsulating MAIN widget and I'm not sure how to go about this. Any input is helpful!
Edit:
The code which fills in main is roughly

```
fillerWidget* filler = new fillerWidget(ui->mainWidget, QString::fromStdString(input1), input2);
QGridLayout* fillerLayout = new QGridLayout();
fillerLayout->addWidget(filler, 0, 0);
ui->mainWidget->setLayout(fillerLayout);
ui->mainWidget->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Preferred, QSizePolicy::Preferred);
filler->adjustSize();
```

Comment: Do you get a runtime warning in the line `ui->mainWidget->setLayout(fillerLayout);`? Ususally, you cannot change the layout of a widget once it was set

Comment: Nope no runtime warning. I clear out the layout before setting it each time the user input needs changes.

Comment: I think there's a problem with the layout of the main part in your sketch. Can you post (a stripped down version) of your .ui file?

Comment: <widget class="QWidget" name="mainWidget" native="true">
        <property name="sizePolicy">
         <sizepolicy hsizetype="MinimumExpanding" vsizetype="MinimumExpanding">
          <horstretch>0</horstretch>
          <verstretch>0</verstretch>
         </sizepolicy>
        </property>
        <property name="minimumSize">
         <size>
          <width>0</width>
          <height>0</height>
         </size>
        </property>
        <property name="font">
         <font>
          <pointsize>18</pointsize>
         </font>
        </property>
       </widget>

Comment: I don't have the character count to space that out, but that's mainWidget from mainwindow.ui

Comment: Have you tried to set a main layout directly from QT Designer (Right click on main/top level widget, set layout...) ?

Comment: I so have a main grid (named gridlayout2) layout of which the mainWidget is a member. I'm not sure that helps me though.

Comment: And what about change the size policy from preferred to expand? [Layout explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4672493/5847906)

Comment: I've done that as well (and having no size policy set) all with no change in the results.

Comment: The important part of the UI file is where you place mainWidget in the form. Can you edit your question and amend the UI file?

Comment: I found my answer here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15183309/how-to-make-new-widgets-fill-available-space